# aws codecommit not giving credentials prompt

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, git-clone, aws-codecommit

I (mistakenly) put invalid codecommit credentials while cloning AWS CodeCommit repository, and now git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east.... is giving 443 error and not prompting for username.

Looks like prompt has been disabled after one unsuccessful attempt, please help on how can I enable it again.

I tried:

```
git clone https://usenmae@git-codecommit.........
```

as well , but even this is not working

I have setup usename using:

```
git config --local user.name <myuser>
```

but even this is not working

Answer (score 5):

Put these lines in your **~/.gitconfig** and save it:

```
[credential "https://git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com"]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@ 
    UseHttpPath = true
```

Then close and open a new window of command line (git bash) and make sure that you are using the URL like: https://git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com without username and password. You can read here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-gc.html

If it didn't work, try to unset the config-credentials and try it again. It's work for me: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/why-am-i-not-prompted-for-password-when-pushing-or-pulling-to-my-repositories-in-bitbucket-cloud-via-https-800293400.html:

`git config --global --unset credential.helper`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've setup remembering of `https` credentials using:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

You can change the credentials in `~/.gitconfig`. Or you can `unset` the helper  using:

```
git config --global credential.helper unset
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly provide username and credentials in your git clone:

```
git clone https://<git-user-from-iam>:<git-pass-from-iam>@git-codecommit.....
```